# How to define an XSD for XML with escaped/serialized XML in it?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I have an XML that contains nested serialized XML within one of its elements. The payload is also a valid formed XML. Also, the payload can contain further level of nesting...

I am looking into how to:

1. Properly define the schema of this XML so that the nested fields are
   also defined.
2. With the definition, any fields can be queried.

Does any XML Schema standard like XSD support this kind of nested XML? Can we use any XML search path tool like XPath to properly search for the nested fields?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event>
<header>
    <field1>Value</field1>
    <field2>Value</field2>
</header>
<body>
    <payload>&lt;?xmlversion=&quot;1.0&quot;encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;event&gt;&lt;header&gt;&lt;field1&gt;Value&lt;/field1&gt;&lt;field2&gt;Value&lt;/field2&gt;&lt;/header&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;payload&gt;&lt;/payload&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/event&gt;
    </payload>
</body>
</event>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your payload is just a text string and will only even be interpreted as text.  If you want to use xsd/xpath or xsl on the payload you'll first need to ensure it is serialized as xml.
Also be aware that any PIs ( your <?xml...> ) will produce invalid xml when buried inside payload, so you'll need to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking into how to:
>
> 1. Properly define the schema of this XML so that the nested fields are
>      also defined.

You've lost the game already by transporting escaped XML rather than actual XML in your `payload` element.

Fix this bad design and use actual XML in `payload` in order to leverage XSD to do validation.

If you can't fix the design, reconstitute the serialized XML into actual XML in a preliminary pass.  Then treat it as real XML against which you can write an XSD, possibly using `xsd:any` as needed.

> 2. With the definition, any fields can be queried.

Again, fix your design or reparse to actual XML.  Then you can use XPath.